# Need to store a password, cannot use hash

Tags: django, django-models

Application has many users, some have accounts on a third party site.

Needing to programmatically access and scrape a the third party site. It has no API or key based auth.

So I've got to either:

- Ask the user for their password to the third party every time we need it. Not really an option as user will not always be present.
- Store the user's password to the third party site.

It pains me to ask, but what's the most safe/practical way to do this? I understand there isn't a completely safe option here.

Comment: Can you tell us the third-party site? There might be another way, or there might be other users in a similar position who could help petition for the provider to provide a better way to access the site.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be to store the passwords encrypted with symmetric cryptogaphy. AES would be a good choice, key could be cached in RAM only, so unless somebody has physical ownership of the machine, it cannot be recovered. It would have to be inserted every time server is rebooted or application restarted.